# Double Drop Down Navigation?

Tags: navigation

Is it possible to have a drop down list for items already in a drop down list in the top bar navigation? Say you click on the first drop down, and it gives you 5 options. Each of those options then have another drop down list with additional options. I'm using SharePoint 2016.

Comment: you have to modify the menu control in the master page with help of SharePoint Designer. Change the property for **MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels** from 1 to 2 to get a drop down of two levels. Please find **SharePoint:AspMenu** as you will find the above tag will be inside this control. Correct me if you need something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extend the global navigation with a drop down menu than you have to modify the menu control in the master page with help of SharePoint Designer. Change the property for **MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels** from 1 to 2 to get a drop down of two levels. You need to find **SharePoint:AspMenu** and the above tag will be inside this control.

If you want to customize the global navigation using some CSS & JS than you can follow steps mentioned in below article.

[Customizing SharePoint 2010 global navigation with Css and jQuery – Part III](https://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/customizing-sharepoint-2010-global-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-%E2%80%93-part-iii/)

Comment: Where do I find the MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels property?

Comment: It will be in your master page as per my explanation...

Comment: You can go through the given link in my answer

Comment: I see 'Master Pages' on the left in Site Objects, but there is a lot of stuff in there. Sorry, this is my first time using SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Just open the master page you are using for your SharePoint site & find the content within it

Comment: The site I'm looking at has 60 different master pages in the master page gallery. Is there one specifically for navigation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41217/discussion-between-luke-k-and-hardik).